# Data storing in a mobile application(windows 8)

Tags: mobile, windows-phone-8, isolatedstorage

I need to store some data to use for a windows8 based mobile application. Data needed to be reuse. For an example need to store 4 phone numbers to send messages and another one to send calls. How can I store data in here. I have heard about isolated storage. Is it the way or can I connect it to a database. Will it application be too heavy if it is connected to a database?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by connect to a database.

In Windows Phone 8, Isolated Storage refers to storage each app has on the phone, and I don't think (I am not sure actually) other apps can access it.  Basically if you need to save something it would look like that.
The following code is to save something:

```
    IsolatedStorageFile myIsolatedStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();

     //create new file
     using (StreamWriter writeFile = new StreamWriter(new IsolatedStorageFileStream("myFile.txt", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, myIsolatedStorage)))
{
string someTextData = "This is some text data to be saved in a new text file in the IsolatedStorage!";
writeFile.WriteLine(someTextData);
writeFile.Close();
}
```

To access that file at anytime you would just do this:

```
    IsolatedStorageFile myIsolatedStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
    IsolatedStorageFileStream fileStream = myIsolatedStorage.OpenFile("myFile.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fileStream))
    {    //Visualize the text data in a TextBlock text
         this.text.Text = reader.ReadLine();
    }
```

Here is the link.  http://www.geekchamp.com/tips/all-about-wp7-isolated-storage-read-and-save-text-files

Isolated Storage would allow you to permenately store files there and retrieve it even when the user quits their application.